Creating RDkit script to show how SMILES strings translate from the structure like the wikipedia image
I would like to start using SMILES strings for some research, and I'd like to show my colleagues how SMILES works. They aren't do much computation, so I want to keep it simple, but the molecules I work with. I see the Wikipedia entry for SMILES and think its perfect:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Molecular_Input_Line_Entry_System
The image on this entry is exactly what I want, but for my molecule. Has anyone generated a code to make those kinds of images?
Thank you,

As source of inspiration, see Daylight's documentation, theory, tutorial, and examples.  Don't forget SMILES a) can encode reactions, b) the extended SMILES by ChemAxon/Marvin equally supported e.g., by CDK depict.  I'm equally curious for answers to turn in (+1).

meaning whats going on underneath ---> mol = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)

@pippo1980 The approach Chem.MolToSmiles(mol) will convert the whole molecule into a SMILES string.  The question by the OP not only wants the conversion, but one which highlights with colors "these characters in the SMILES string correspond to alkyl chain A, these to chain B, to saturated ring C, to aromatic ring D", etc.

Sorry for my bad english : I  said underneath meaning under the hood of  the MolToSmiles function: the ineers of the alghoritm that does thd conversion. If I am not wrong it should calculate that fragments ......Didnt find the siurce code for that, but in any case I think is C and does not expose anything to python. Would be nice to have it though

Something like Chem.MolToSmiles(mol).fragments()

cant read C but maybe the fragments are somewhere near https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/b5d6a3dba719244aa7791e6dccc7e549d62ed060/Code/GraphMol/SmilesParse/SmilesWrite.cpp#L528

Chem.MolToSmiles(mol) is a func so
Chem.MolToSmiles(mol).fragments() is not feasible     maybe we need Chem.MolToSmilesFragments(mol)

https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/b5d6a3dba719244aa7791e6dccc7e549d62ed060/Code/GraphMol/SmilesParse/SmilesWrite.cpp#L397   std::string FragmentSmilesConstruct(....)    this is where the mol is navigated by the  algorithm that extract all the branches and branches of branch (the one inside the Round Brackets in the SMILES strings

OK; preamble needed dont know c++ so bear with me, just trying to figure out the path that could led to an answer to your question.
Decided to use   rdkit FragmentSmilesConstruct where the mol (single molecule, not a bunch of them, is translated to SMILES according to the mol  object in memory (RWMol or RoMol not sure wich) inside the
SmileParse/SmilesWrite functionality of RDKit. Going from SMILES to mol is actually to difficult to me (can't figure out how the mol obj is created, and how it works. If anybody know of a Docs like the one for Biopython PDB Structure representation  please send me a link.
I just duplicated some parts of these files changing some names and the returned res string (in SmilesWrite.ccp); locations of files in RDKIT source code :
rdkit-Release_2024_03_6/Code/GraphMol/Wrap/rdmolfiles.cpp

rdkit-Release_2024_03_6/Code/GraphMol/SmilesParse/SmilesWrite.cpp

rdkit-Release_2024_03_6/Code/GraphMol/SmilesParse/SmilesWrite.h

For rdmolfiles.ccp just copied here line 1591 and here line 1624
python::def("MolToSmiles",.... block
to
python::def("MolToSmilesFragments"....,
Then in SmilesWrite.h :
after line 141 :
namespace detail {
RDKIT_SMILESPARSE_EXPORT std::string MolToSmiles(
    const ROMol &mol, const SmilesWriteParams &params, bool doingCXSmiles);
}

added:
namespace detail {
RDKIT_SMILESPARSE_EXPORT std::string MolToSmilesFragments(
    const ROMol &mol, const SmilesWriteParams &params, bool doingCXSmiles);
}

same for line 148 copying all the block
changing RDKIT_SMILESPARSE_EXPORT std::string MolToSmiles(
to RDKIT_SMILESPARSE_EXPORT std::string MolToSmilesFragments(
Finally in  SmilesWrite.cpp :
added:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

then at line 517 added:
std::string FragmentSmilesConstructMine(
    ROMol &mol, int atomIdx, std::vector<Canon::AtomColors> &colors,
    const UINT_VECT &ranks, const SmilesWriteParams &params,
    std::vector<unsigned int> &atomOrdering,
    std::vector<unsigned int> &bondOrdering,
    const boost::dynamic_bitset<> *atomsInPlay = nullptr,
    const boost::dynamic_bitset<> *bondsInPlay = nullptr,
    const std::vector<std::string> *atomSymbols = nullptr,
    const std::vector<std::string> *bondSymbols = nullptr) {
  PRECONDITION(!atomsInPlay || atomsInPlay->size() >= mol.getNumAtoms(),
               "bad atomsInPlay");
  PRECONDITION(!bondsInPlay || bondsInPlay->size() >= mol.getNumBonds(),
               "bad bondsInPlay");
  PRECONDITION(!atomSymbols || atomSymbols->size() >= mol.getNumAtoms(),
               "bad atomSymbols");
  PRECONDITION(!bondSymbols || bondSymbols->size() >= mol.getNumBonds(),
               "bad bondSymbols");
  if (params.doKekule) {
    if (atomsInPlay && bondsInPlay) {
      MolOps::details::KekulizeFragment(static_cast<RWMol &>(mol), *atomsInPlay,
                                        *bondsInPlay);
    } else {
      MolOps::Kekulize(static_cast<RWMol &>(mol));
    }
  }

  Canon::MolStack molStack;
  // try to prevent excessive reallocation
  molStack.reserve(mol.getNumAtoms() + mol.getNumBonds());
  
  int molat;
  int molbn;
  molat =  mol.getNumAtoms();
  molbn =  mol.getNumBonds();
  //std::cout << "mol.getNumAtoms() !!! " << molat << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "mol.getNumBonds() !!! " << molbn << std::endl;
  
  std::cout << "FragmentSmilesConstructMine in use !!! " << std::endl;
  std::stringstream res;
  
  std::map<int, int> ringClosureMap;
  int ringIdx, closureVal;
  if (!params.canonical) {
    mol.setProp(common_properties::_StereochemDone, 1);
  }
  std::list<unsigned int> ringClosuresToErase;
  
  if (params.canonical && params.doIsomericSmiles) {
    Canon::canonicalizeEnhancedStereo(mol, &ranks);
  }
  Canon::canonicalizeFragment(mol, atomIdx, colors, ranks, molStack,
                              bondsInPlay, bondSymbols, params.doIsomericSmiles,
                              params.doRandom);
  Bond *bond = nullptr;
  
  int branch = 0;
  int numbranch = 0;
  
  //Create an empty List
  std::vector<int> numbranchlist;
  
  numbranchlist.push_back(0);
    
  std::string branchstr = "";
  for (auto &mSE : molStack) {
  
    //std::cout << "mSE.type : " << mSE.type << std::endl;
    
    switch (mSE.type) {
      //std::cout << "mSE.type : " << mSE.type << std::endl;
      case Canon::MOL_STACK_ATOM:
        for (auto rclosure : ringClosuresToErase) {
          ringClosureMap.erase(rclosure);
        }
        ringClosuresToErase.clear();
        
        if (!atomSymbols) {
          res << GetAtomSmiles(mSE.obj.atom, params);
          res <<"_";
          res << mSE.obj.atom->getIdx();
          branch = numbranchlist.back();
          branchstr = std::to_string(branch);
          res <<",";
          res << branchstr;
          res <<";";
        } else {
          res << (*atomSymbols)[mSE.obj.atom->getIdx()];
        }
        atomOrdering.push_back(mSE.obj.atom->getIdx());
        break;
      case Canon::MOL_STACK_BOND:
        bond = mSE.obj.bond;
        
        if (!bondSymbols) {
        } else {
          res << (*bondSymbols)[bond->getIdx()];
        }
        bondOrdering.push_back(bond->getIdx());
        break;
      case Canon::MOL_STACK_RING:
        
        ringIdx = mSE.number;

        if (ringClosureMap.count(ringIdx)) {
          // the index is already in the map ->
          //   we're closing a ring, so grab
          //   the index and then delete the value:
          closureVal = ringClosureMap[ringIdx];
          ringClosuresToErase.push_back(ringIdx);
        } else {
          // we're opening a new ring, find the index for it:
          closureVal = 1;
          bool done = false;
          // EFF: there's got to be a more efficient way to do this
          while (!done) {
            std::map<int, int>::iterator mapIt;
            for (mapIt = ringClosureMap.begin(); mapIt != ringClosureMap.end();
                 ++mapIt) {
              if (mapIt->second == closureVal) {
                break;
              }
            }
            if (mapIt == ringClosureMap.end()) {
              done = true;
            } else {
              closureVal += 1;
            }
          }
          ringClosureMap[ringIdx] = closureVal;
        }
        if (closureVal < 10) {
          res << (char)(closureVal + '0');
        } else if (closureVal < 100) {
          res << '%' << closureVal;
        } else {  // use extension to OpenSMILES
          res << "%(" << closureVal << ')';
        }
        break;
      case Canon::MOL_STACK_BRANCH_OPEN:
        
        numbranch +=1;
        numbranchlist.push_back(numbranch);
        branch = numbranchlist.back();
        branchstr = std::to_string(branch);
        for (auto v : numbranchlist)
            std::cout <<"numbranchlist list opening : " << v << "\n";
        std::cout << "end print numbranchlist list" << std::endl;
        break;
      case Canon::MOL_STACK_BRANCH_CLOSE:
        numbranchlist.push_back(numbranchlist[numbranchlist.size() - 2]);
        branch =  numbranchlist.back();
        branchstr = std::to_string(branch);
        for (auto v : numbranchlist)
            std::cout <<"numbranchlist list closing : " << v << "\n";
        std::cout << "end print numbranchlist list" << std::endl;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return res.str();
}


and after line 769   added:
namespace SmilesWrite {
namespace detail {
std::string MolToSmilesFragments(const ROMol &mol, const SmilesWriteParams &params,
                        bool doingCXSmiles) {
  if (!mol.getNumAtoms()) {
    return "";
  }
  PRECONDITION(
      params.rootedAtAtom < 0 ||
          static_cast<unsigned int>(params.rootedAtAtom) < mol.getNumAtoms(),
      "rootedAtomAtom must be less than the number of atoms");
  int rootedAtAtom = params.rootedAtAtom;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> fragsMolAtomMapping;
  auto mols =
      MolOps::getMolFrags(mol, false, nullptr, &fragsMolAtomMapping, false);
  // we got the mapping between fragments and atoms; repeat that for bonds
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> fragsMolBondMapping;
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> atsPresent(mol.getNumAtoms());
  std::vector<int> bondsInFrag;
  bondsInFrag.reserve(mol.getNumBonds());
  for (const auto &atsInFrag : fragsMolAtomMapping) {
    atsPresent.reset();
    bondsInFrag.clear();
    for (auto aidx : atsInFrag) {
      atsPresent.set(aidx);
    }
    for (const auto bnd : mol.bonds()) {
      if (atsPresent[bnd->getBeginAtomIdx()] &&
          atsPresent[bnd->getEndAtomIdx()]) {
        bondsInFrag.push_back(bnd->getIdx());
      }
    }
    fragsMolBondMapping.push_back(bondsInFrag);
  }

  std::vector<std::string> vfragsmi(mols.size());

  //    for(unsigned i=0; i<fragsMolAtomMapping.size(); i++){
  //      std::cout << i << ": ";
  //      for(unsigned j=0; j<fragsMolAtomMapping[i].size(); j++){
  //        std::cout << j <<"("<<fragsMolAtomMapping[i][j]<<") ";
  //      }
  //      std::cout << std::endl;
  //    }

  std::vector<std::vector<RDKit::UINT>> allAtomOrdering;
  std::vector<std::vector<RDKit::UINT>> allBondOrdering;
  for (unsigned fragIdx = 0; fragIdx < mols.size(); fragIdx++) {
    ROMol *tmol = mols[fragIdx].get();

    // update property cache
    std::vector<int> atomMapNums(tmol->getNumAtoms(), 0);
    for (auto atom : tmol->atoms()) {
      if (params.ignoreAtomMapNumbers) {
        atomMapNums[atom->getIdx()] = atom->getAtomMapNum();
        atom->setAtomMapNum(0);
      }
      atom->updatePropertyCache(false);
    }

    // clean up the chirality on any atom that is marked as chiral,
    // but that should not be:
    if (params.doIsomericSmiles) {
      tmol->setProp(common_properties::_doIsoSmiles, 1);
      if (!tmol->hasProp(common_properties::_StereochemDone)) {
        MolOps::assignStereochemistry(*tmol, true);
      }
    }
    if (!doingCXSmiles) {
      // remove any stereo groups that may be present. Otherwise they will be
      // used in the canonicalization
      std::vector<StereoGroup> noStereoGroups;
      tmol->setStereoGroups(noStereoGroups);
      // remove any wiggle bonds, unspecified double bond stereochemistry, or
      // dative bonds (if we aren't doing dative bonds in the standard SMILES)
      for (auto bond : tmol->bonds()) {
        if (bond->getBondDir() == Bond::BondDir::UNKNOWN ||
            bond->getBondDir() == Bond::BondDir::EITHERDOUBLE) {
          bond->setBondDir(Bond::BondDir::NONE);
        }
        if (bond->getStereo() == Bond::BondStereo::STEREOANY) {
          bond->setStereo(Bond::BondStereo::STEREONONE);
        }
      }
      // if other CXSMILES features are added to the canonicalization code
      // in the future, they should be removed here.
    }

    if (doingCXSmiles || !params.includeDativeBonds) {
      // do not output dative bonds in the SMILES if we are doing CXSmiles (we
      // output coordinate bonds there) or if the flag is set to ignore them
      for (auto bond : tmol->bonds()) {
        if (bond->getBondType() == Bond::DATIVE) {
          // we are intentionally only handling DATIVE here. The other weird
          // RDKit dative alternatives really shouldn't ever show up.
          bond->setBondType(Bond::SINGLE);
          // update the explicit valence of the begin atom since the implicit
          // valence will no longer be properly perceived
          bond->getBeginAtom()->calcExplicitValence(false);
        }
      }
    }

#if 0
    std::cout << "----------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MolToSmilesFragments:" << std::endl;
    tmol->debugMol(std::cout);
    std::cout << "----------------------------" << std::endl;
#endif

    if (params.doRandom && rootedAtAtom == -1) {
      // need to find a random atom id between 0 and mol.getNumAtoms()
      // exclusively
      rootedAtAtom = getRandomGenerator()() % tmol->getNumAtoms();
    }

    std::string res;
    unsigned int nAtoms = tmol->getNumAtoms();
    std::vector<unsigned int> ranks(nAtoms);
    std::vector<unsigned int> atomOrdering;
    std::vector<unsigned int> bondOrdering;

    if (params.canonical) {
      if (tmol->hasProp("_canonicalRankingNumbers")) {
        for (const auto atom : tmol->atoms()) {
          unsigned int rankNum = 0;
          atom->getPropIfPresent("_canonicalRankingNumber", rankNum);
          ranks[atom->getIdx()] = rankNum;
        }
      } else {
        bool breakTies = true;
        Canon::rankMolAtoms(*tmol, ranks, breakTies, params.doIsomericSmiles,
                            params.doIsomericSmiles);
      }
      if (params.ignoreAtomMapNumbers) {
        for (auto atom : tmol->atoms()) {
          atom->setAtomMapNum(atomMapNums[atom->getIdx()]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      std::iota(ranks.begin(), ranks.end(), 0);
    }
#ifdef VERBOSE_CANON
    for (unsigned int tmpI = 0; tmpI < ranks.size(); tmpI++) {
      std::cout << tmpI << " " << ranks[tmpI] << " "
                << *(tmol->getAtomWithIdx(tmpI)) << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    std::vector<Canon::AtomColors> colors(nAtoms, Canon::WHITE_NODE);
    int nextAtomIdx = -1;
    std::string subSmi;

    // find the next atom for a traverse
    if (rootedAtAtom >= 0) {
      nextAtomIdx = rootedAtAtom;
      rootedAtAtom = -1;
    } else {
      unsigned int nextRank = nAtoms + 1;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nAtoms; i++) {
        if (colors[i] == Canon::WHITE_NODE && ranks[i] < nextRank) {
          nextRank = ranks[i];
          nextAtomIdx = i;
        }
      }
    }
    CHECK_INVARIANT(nextAtomIdx >= 0, "no start atom found");
    subSmi = SmilesWrite::FragmentSmilesConstructMine(
        *tmol, nextAtomIdx, colors, ranks, params, atomOrdering, bondOrdering);
    
    //char c_append = '-';
    //subSmi += c_append;
    
    res += subSmi;
    vfragsmi[fragIdx] = res;

    for (unsigned int &vit : atomOrdering) {
      vit = fragsMolAtomMapping[fragIdx][vit];  // Lookup the Id in the
                                                // original molecule
    }
    allAtomOrdering.push_back(atomOrdering);
    for (unsigned int &vit : bondOrdering) {
      vit = fragsMolBondMapping[fragIdx][vit];  // Lookup the Id in the
                                                // original molecule
    }
    allBondOrdering.push_back(bondOrdering);
  }

  std::string result;
  std::vector<unsigned int> flattenedAtomOrdering;
  flattenedAtomOrdering.reserve(mol.getNumAtoms());
  std::vector<unsigned int> flattenedBondOrdering;
  flattenedBondOrdering.reserve(mol.getNumBonds());
  if (params.canonical) {
    // Sort the vfragsmi, but also sort the atom and bond order vectors into
    // the same order
    typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<unsigned int>,
                       std::vector<unsigned int>>
        tplType;
    std::vector<tplType> tmp(vfragsmi.size());
    for (unsigned int ti = 0; ti < vfragsmi.size(); ++ti) {
      tmp[ti] = std::make_tuple(vfragsmi[ti], allAtomOrdering[ti],
                                allBondOrdering[ti]);
    }

    for (unsigned int ti = 0; ti < vfragsmi.size(); ++ti) {
            
      //char cappend = '-';
      
      
      result += std::get<0>(tmp[ti]);
      
      //result += cappend;
      
      if (ti < vfragsmi.size() - 1) {
      
        result += ".";
      }
      flattenedAtomOrdering.insert(flattenedAtomOrdering.end(),
                                   std::get<1>(tmp[ti]).begin(),
                                   std::get<1>(tmp[ti]).end());
      flattenedBondOrdering.insert(flattenedBondOrdering.end(),
                                   std::get<2>(tmp[ti]).begin(),
                                   std::get<2>(tmp[ti]).end());
    }
  } else {  // Not canonical
    for (auto &i : allAtomOrdering) {
      flattenedAtomOrdering.insert(flattenedAtomOrdering.end(), i.begin(),
                                   i.end());
    }
    for (auto &i : allBondOrdering) {
      flattenedBondOrdering.insert(flattenedBondOrdering.end(), i.begin(),
                                   i.end());
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vfragsmi.size(); ++i) {
      result += vfragsmi[i];
      
      //char cappend = '-';
      //result += cappend;
      
      if (i < vfragsmi.size() - 1) {
        result += ".";
      }
    }
  }
  mol.setProp(common_properties::_smilesAtomOutputOrder, flattenedAtomOrdering,
              true);
  mol.setProp(common_properties::_smilesBondOutputOrder, flattenedBondOrdering,
              true);
              

  return result;
}
}  // namespace detail
}  // namespace SmilesWrite
std::string MolToSmilesFragments(const ROMol &mol, const SmilesWriteParams &params) {
  bool doingCXSmiles = false;
  return SmilesWrite::detail::MolToSmilesFragments(mol, params, doingCXSmiles);
}


Build and installed this modded RDKit version
where MolToSmilesFragments points to    FragmentSmilesConstructMine and returns (be sure to feed to MolToSmilesFragment just a one mol string, and not a multiple one, result if any  won't be processed right by my Python script)
a string like for orig_smi :  N1CCN(CC1)C(C(F)=C2)=CC(=C2C4=O)N(C3CC3)C=C4C(=O)O 
that looks like :
O_22,0;C_21,0;O_23,1;c_20,0;c_19,0;n_15,0;C_16,2;C_17,2;C_18,2;c_11,0;c_10,0;c_6,0;N_3,3;C_2,3;C_1,3;N_0,3;C_5,3;C_4,3;c_7,0;F_8,4;c_9,0;c_12,0;c_13,0;O_14,0 ;
where first char in each block separated by semicolon (O_22,0) is the Smiles Atom String , the second is the atom index in the mol object and the third is the branch_opened number in the mol structure/object/whatever I should call it.
Then my Python script that uses DrawMoleculeWithHighlights:
import rdkit
print('\n-------------------------------')
print('\n rdkit Version : ', rdkit.__version__)
print('\n-------------------------------')
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from IPython.core.display import SVG
from io import BytesIO
from cairosvg import svg2png
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

# orig_smi = 'C1CNCCN1c(c2)c(F)cc3c2N(C4CC4)C=C(C3=O)C(=O)O'
orig_smi ='N1CCN(CC1)C(C(F)=C2)=CC(=C2C4=O)N(C3CC3)C=C4C(=O)O'  # from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Molecular_Input_Line_Entry_System#/media/File:SMILES.png
#orig_smi ="O=C(O)c1cn(C2CC2)c2cc(N3CCNc4c3cccc4)c(F)cc2c1=O" #### added ring to ciprofloxacin
# orig_smi ='O=C(O)c1cn(C2CC2)c2cc(N3CCNc4c3cc3c(c4)cccc3)c(F)cc2c1=O' ## added 2 rings to ciprofloxacin

cipro_mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(orig_smi)                              
# cipro_mol_img = Draw.MolToImage(cipro_mol)
# cipro_mol_img.show()
# cipro_core_smi = Chem.MolToSmiles(cipro_mol)

print('\norig_smi : ', orig_smi,'\n')

# print('\ncipro_core_smi : ', cipro_core_smi, '\n')
# cipro_mol_core = Chem.MolFromSmiles(cipro_core_smi)

print('\nfragments : ')
# frags = Chem.MolToSmilesFragments(cipro_mol_core)
frags = Chem.MolToSmilesFragments(cipro_mol)
print('\n\nfrags :' , frags)


def convert(in_str):
    result = {}
    for tokens in in_str.rstrip(';').split(";"):  
        print(tokens)
        current_tuple = []
        for token in tokens.split('_')[1].split(','):   
            print(token)
            current_tuple.append(int(token))
            print('*current_tuple, :', (*current_tuple,))
        current_tuple = (*current_tuple,)
        # result.append((*current_tuple,))
        if current_tuple[1] in result:  
            result[current_tuple[1]] = result[current_tuple[1]] + (current_tuple[0],)
        else: 
            result[current_tuple[1]] = (current_tuple[0],) 
    return result

frag_atoms = convert(frags)
print('\n\nfrag_atoms : ' , frag_atoms)


number_of_colors = len(frag_atoms)
colors = iter([tuple(np.random.rand(3)) for i in range(number_of_colors)])

drawer = Draw.rdMolDraw2D.MolDraw2DSVG(800,800, -1,-1)
dopts = drawer.drawOptions()
dopts.addAtomIndices = True
dopts.addBondIndices = True

highlight_bond = {}
print('\n\nfrag_atoms.values() :', frag_atoms.values())
for num , atom in frag_atoms.items(): 
    highlight_bond[num] = []
 
print('\n\nhighlight_bond : ', highlight_bond)
    
for number, atoms in frag_atoms.items():
    for i in range(cipro_mol.GetNumBonds()):
        bond = cipro_mol.GetBondWithIdx(i)
        begin_aid = bond.GetBeginAtomIdx()
        end_aid = bond.GetEndAtomIdx()
        if begin_aid in atoms and end_aid in atoms:
            highlight_bond[number].append(i)
            
print('\n\nhighlight_bond : ', highlight_bond)
highlight_atom_map = {}
highlight_bond_map = {}
highlight_radii = {}

colors_copy = deepcopy(colors)
# print('\n\natoms :', atoms)
for _atoms in frag_atoms.values():
    color = next(colors_copy)
    for atom in _atoms: 
        highlight_atom_map[atom] = [color]
        highlight_radii[atom] = 0.4
        
colors_copy = deepcopy(colors)
for bonds in highlight_bond.values():
    color = next(colors_copy)
    for bond in bonds:
        # print(bond)
        highlight_bond_map[bond] = [color]
        
for atoms in frag_atoms.values():
    color = next(colors)
    for atom in atoms: 
        highlight_atom_map[atom] = [color]
        highlight_radii[atom] = 0.4

# cipro mol or cipromol_core
drawer.DrawMoleculeWithHighlights(cipro_mol,
                                   "try",
                                   highlight_atom_map=highlight_atom_map,
                                   highlight_bond_map=highlight_bond_map,
                                   highlight_radii=highlight_radii,
                                   highlight_linewidth_multipliers={})

drawer.FinishDrawing()
svg_get = drawer.GetDrawingText()
svg = SVG(svg_get)  # for jupiter ???
print('\n\n\n svg : ' , svg)
svg_data = BytesIO(svg.data.encode())
with open('output_2.svg', 'w') as f:     
    f.write(svg.data)
# png = svg2png(bytestring=svg_data.read()) OR BELOW:
png = svg2png(bytestring=svg_get)
pil_img = Image.open(BytesIO(png)).convert('RGBA')
pil_img.save('pil.png')
print(type(pil_img))  
pil_img.show()

Some of the result output (its there just to keep track of what Iam doing):
frag_atoms :  {0: (22, 21, 20, 19, 15, 11, 10, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14), 1: (23,), 2: (16, 17, 18), 3: (3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4), 4: (8,)}


frag_atoms.values() : dict_values([(22, 21, 20, 19, 15, 11, 10, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14), (23,), (16, 17, 18), (3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4), (8,)])


highlight_bond :  {0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}


highlight_bond :  {0: [6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 26], 1: [], 2: [16, 17, 25], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 23], 4: []}

Result Pics :

That looks different from the depiction in Wikipedia, maybe different algorithm or maybe my effort is wrong. Have a look.


+1 for a detailed first answer, but please improve the spacing in your code (I have done some of it for you).
